# My javascript code does not work with the result of work php

Tags: javascript, php

I have website on wordpress, and i use Search & Filter Pro plugin for filter my posts.

[image: https://prnt.sc/slmx7z]

I need to sort filter fields by posts count.The plugin does not provide the necessary functionality, so I decided to use javascript to sort.

```
const getFilterFieldDepMeth = () => {
      const container = document.querySelector(
        ".sf-field-taxonomy-deposit_methods ul"
      );
      const listField = container.querySelectorAll("li");
      let arrayList = [];
      listField.forEach((item) => {
        arrayList.push(item);
      });
      const sortedListField = arrayList.sort((a, b) => {
        const elem1 = parseInt(b.getAttribute("data-sf-count"));
        const elem2 = parseInt(a.getAttribute("data-sf-count"));
        return elem1 - elem2;
      });
      sortedListField.map((item) => {
        container.appendChild(item);
      });
    };

    getFilterFieldDepMeth();
```

The code works and can show the result anywhere but I can’t influence the DOM in the filter block. I also cannot delete filter fields.

Comment: Where id you place this piece of javascript?

Comment: `.map()` is not the right tool

Comment: in js file and plug beforeend body

Comment: I tried with foreach(). does not work either